# Configuring WLAN with router connected to modem

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, modem

I currently own an ADSL modem. I am planning to buy a D-Link DIR 600 Wireless Router, for setting up a wireless network to play Counter Strike with my buddies. I have a few questions.

1. How do I set up the router? Am I correct in thinking that I should connect my telephone wire to my modem, my modem to my router, and then my router to my PC?
2. If I switch on WiFi on the router and let my friends connect to the network to play CS, will the game be actually be played locally or through the internet?
3. How do I set up only LAN-sharing, without internet? Is it easy to switch between LAN-only sharing and traditional internet sharing?

**EDIT :** My ADSL modem is also a router, but it has only 1 ethernet port, which is currently connected to my PC. So I will be connecting my wireless router to my ADSL modem/router.

To add to question #3:

After I finish playing CS, I want to be able to continue using the internet on my PC, after switching off WiFi; i.e., stopping my router from beaming my internet connection. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The existing ADSL router is all you need to connect to the internet.  Adding a second router is both pointless and expensive.  A cheap cable router of the type you are looking at will not work with your ADSL router.

What you require is a small (maybe 4 of 5 port) switch to increase the number of ethernet ports available on the existing router, and a wireless access point to share the network out as and when you want it.

[image: Sample Network]

When you want to disable all access to the network through wireless means you can just unplug or turn off the wireless access point.

Comment: Okay, you've answered my 2nd question. I've added a bit of clarification for my other questions.

Comment: The DIR-600 is a cable router, not an ADSL router.  It is designed to connect to a modem which bridges the ADSL or Cable internet connection into a PPPoE signal.  If your existing modem is just a modem (you have to run Dialup Networking on your PC to connect to the internet) then this is fine.  Otherwise you won't get the Dlink to work with your existing setup and you'll be sorely disappointed and frustrated.

Comment: If your current modem is truly a router then you don't want a second router at all but a Wireless Access Point, and maybe a small switch.  Then you can link the existing router to the switch, your PC to the switch and the Wireless Access Point to the switch.  Your friends then link to the Wireless Access Point through WiFi.  When you don't want the wireless to work, just turn it off (physically.  pull the power.)

Comment: D'oh! Thanks, I was almost about to order one on eBay! Just to be sure, my current ADSL modem/router is the UT Starcom 300R2U (http://www.utstar.com/Document_Library/0046.pdf) and it uses PPPoE to connect to the internet. So is this not compatible with a ADSL router? Should I buy only an access point?

Comment: Unless the Starcom is running in bridging mode (which I seriously doubt) then you will not be able to connect this to another router of the type you are looking at.  What you want is a small (4 or 5 port) switch and a wireless access point.  See http://imgur.com/jNxZx

Answer (score 1):

1. If your router is a `ADSL-modem/router`, you can get the `ADSL modem` out and just connect the router (you'll need to know the ADSL configuration of your ISP : protocols + credentials). But else your are right. The router will get the public IP from the modem and dispatch to the other networks (Affecting an IP to each if `DHCP` is active).
2. If your friends connects to the wireless and your are playing a game, it will be on LAN if the server is on the `LAN` and you connect to it via a local address (`192.168.x.x` for example), but if the server is online, it would of course, be through internet. Undefined behaviour if you join a game from a list on the internet and it "fortunately" ends being a server hosted locally : would depend on the games I guess.
3. You can just disconnect the router from the modem, or maybe the router has an option to close a port. Then all traffic can only go between peers.
   Be advise that LAN-Sharing for file *etc* may have to be enabled on the OSes. For games, it's generally not a problem since it's just networking stuff. Then if the hosts can pings that should be ok (!!Firewalls!!)

Comment: But the DIR 600 does not have a port for the telephone jack! Only my ADSL-modem/router has one. So I have to connect it in this order [telephone wire -> ADSL modem/router -> wireless router -> PC], right?

Comment: Yep: see the `But else your are right. ` thing :P